# Exact number of times a question is viewed?

Tags: support, views

Is it possible to determine exactly how many times a question has been viewed on any Stack Exchange network site?

After a page has been viewed for around a thousand times, all I get to see is view count rounded to the nearest thousand (or million).

Is there a way to get an exact count of how many times a question has been viewed?

Comment: Yeah, just hover over the `1k views`, it'll say `1036`. Now to find the duplicate...